# PGFplots/groupplots/tikz use whichever is lower: xmin or data

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I'm making a lot of plots with pgfplots/groupplots/tikz from csv files, using `\addplot[...] table[...]{file.csv}` or `\nextgroupplot[...] table[...]{file.csv}`

Some files have both positive and negative x-coordinates, some have all positive.

I'd like to set `xmin=0` if all the coordinates are positive, and have xmin determined automatically if the coordinates are negative - so `xmin` is always 0 or lower, and all data is always shown.

Is there a way to determine this automatically, without just looking at the data and adding `xmin=0` to those that don't cross the axis? Something like `if(automatically_determined_xmin>0){xmin=0}`, that would preferably go in `\begin{groupplot}[this bit]` to avoid repeating it in every `\nextgroupplot[one of these]`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}[11pt]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size=2 by 1
                    },
                axis y line=middle,
                axis x line=bottom,
                x=3cm,
                xtick distance=0.5
            ]
        \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot[] table[x=x,y=y]{
            x y
            -0.1 1
            1 -1
            };
        \nextgroupplot[]
        \addplot[] table[x=x,y=y]{
            x y
            0.9 1
            1 -1
            };
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: two plots in a groupplot, the first crosses zero, the second doesn't]
A major symptom of the problem is that the second plot only has 1 x-label, so doesn't have a sense of scale. Also I'd like the y-axis to go through x=0. In reality there are enough of this type of figures that I could miss one by doing things manually

Comment: Would be easier for answerers if you include a minimal (non)working example.

Comment: edited with mwe

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself for reference because I've found a solution (but not quite ideal because it needs an addition to every `\nextgroupplot`):
Add `\addplot[mark=none] coordinates { (0,0) };` to each plot, and leave `xmin` unset.

`[mark=none]` still leaves the line enabled, but it looks like it doesn't draw a line with only one point, so there's no extra floating dot at the origin or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This answer use some undocumented feature/trick, and I do not fully understand what is happening. There is no guarantee that it will keep working and it does not break anything.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group size=2 by 1
},
axis y line=middle,
axis x line=bottom,
x=3cm,
xtick distance=0.5,
execute at end survey={\pgfmathparse{\csname pgfplots@xmin\endcsname<0?\csname pgfplots@xmin\endcsname:0} \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@xmin\endcsname=\pgfmathresult},
]
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] table[x=x,y=y]{
x y
-0.1 1
1 -1
};
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] table[x=x,y=y]{
x y
0.9 1
1 -1
};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two plots]

I would use

```
\addplot[mark=none, forget plot] coordinates { (0,0) };
```

as in your own answer - notice `forget plot` so that it is not counted as a real plot in e.g. the legend.